# Determine minimum data to start with building model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, supervised-learning, regression-strategies

We have developed a basic Regression framework where we try to build models for over 100 configs(stored in a file).
To run :

```
python workflow.py -s <start_date> -e <end_date>
```

Components-

```
Data:
we do hive query for given start & end date separately for each of the configs to fetch data.
There are 60 predictors and 1 response column.

Visualization , analysis, cleaning - 
1) create plots(bar, correlation)
2) outlier removal/imputation.
3) others

Build models - 
1) GBM, RF, CART 

Scoring-
R2 , RMSE

Dump Learning curve & predicted vs actual plots.

Use a json registry to dump scores for each platform.
```

Consider each component is complete in itself.

The problem we are faced is when we run our framework with fixed date range input(say 1week)-

```
There are platforms that have over > 80K rows wherease others may have <300rows.
Models with good data points have R2(train/test) in range of 0.7-0.8,
wherease for rest R2 is ~1 (Overfit).
```

We should be adding data for these configs with less data points.
Right now, we check each Learning curve and find out if we should add more data.
This is a manual process and a tedious one.

```
Is there a way that we can determne -
1) How many data points is mandatory to start with ?
2) what can we do programmatically to determine that the model needs more data or not?(We can retry by increasing the date range)
3) Anything we can do programmatically to find if model is overfit/underfit and take remedial measures ?
```

We want to automate the framework to maximum possible extent.

I think its not possible to automate 100% to create good fit models.
Manual intervention is required.

Please suggest any enhancement that can be done. I can do the exploring.